# Cordova getFile and external SD card

Tags: android, cordova

```
$window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fs) {
     // case 1
     fs.root.getFile('/storage/emulated/0/VIDEO0048.mp4', null, ok, fail);
     //case 2
     fs.root.getFile('/storage/ext_sd/VIDEO0048.mp4', null, ok, fail);
```

}

In the above code using the Cordova file plugin v1.3.3 on Android, case 1 works and case 2 doesn't. For case 2 it reports error 1000. I know both files exist, one in internal storage and one on the SD card and I have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions set in the manifest. Has anyone used the Cordova file plugin to access files on the SD card this way and got it working?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to my own question in case it helps anyone else.

To get this to work I upgraded to the 2.1.0 version of cordova-plugin-file and instead of using getFile (that no longer takes an absolute path) I used $window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL to get a fileEntry which worked for both internal and SD card paths. The only wrinkle was that I had to prepend "file://" to my path so that it looked like this "file:///storage/ext_sd/VIDEO0048.mp4" when passed into resolveLocalFileSystemURL.